# Write a program that will generate 1000 random integers in the range 0-49. (C++)

Tags: c++, random

I've looked around other questions asked here but can't quite find what I need.

I've got this question;

Write a program that will generate 1000 random integers in the range 0-49. It should count and report how many were in the range 0-24 and how many were in the range 25-49.

and this is what I have so far;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>   //For time()
#include<cstdlib> //For rand() and srand()


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    int counter = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (counter = 0; counter < 1000; counter++) {
    {
        x = rand() % 49 + 1;
        if (x >= 0 && x <= 24)
        {
            y++;
        }
        else if (x > 24 && x <= 49)
        {
            z++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of numbers between 0-24: " << y << endl;
    cout << "Number of numbers between 25-49: " << z << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
   }
 }
```

It loops once but I can't understand how to get it to loop over and over until 1000 numbers have been generated and categorized.

I'm pretty new to C++ so could someone explain how to get this to loop? Have I missed something super obvious?

Comment: you can use longer variable names, friend, so instead of "z" you could call it number_of_results_twentyfive_and_higher  .. will make your code easier to read 10 months down the road.

Comment: Voting to close as silly typo. Too many braces, returning inside the loop.

Comment: `rand() % 49 + 1` produces numbers in the range 1-49. To produce numbers in the range 0-49 use `rand() % 50` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya gots one too many curly brackets in your `for` loop.  Becuase of that, your `return` and `cout`s are happening within the `for` loop.  It gets one number, prints out, then gets returned before it can come back around.  Try this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>   //For time()
#include<cstdlib> //For rand() and srand()

using namespace std;
int main()
{    
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (counter = 0; counter < 1000; counter++)
    {
        int x;            //See Note #3 Below
        int counter = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;
        x = rand() % 50;  //See Note #1 Below
        if (x < 25)       //See Note #2 Below
        {
            y++;
        }
        else
        {
            z++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of numbers between 0-24: " << y << endl;
    cout << "Number of numbers between 25-49: " << z << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;   
 }
```

**3 notes about your Code**:

1. Your random number generator is only getting numbers 1-49, not 0-49.
2. You don't really need to structure your if statement that way.  All you have to do is say, "If it's less than 25, put it in one bucket, otherwise, put it in the other."
3. You may want to declare variables in the scope they'll be used.  In this case, your `for` loop.

Comment: It's perfect, for some definition of *"perfect"* (not mine). It doesn't meet your specification, and if you have a fair PRNG, you'll see a bias towards the count of numbers in the upper interval.

Comment: Doesn't this just generate numbers between 1-49?

Comment: @cwschmidt - that wasn't the op's question.  But, I'll revise the answer, because that's apparently what we're doing now... answering questions and performing free code review.

Comment: This is not part of a code review. It is strictly a problem with the code. If you want to perform a code review, you'd have to move `x` and `counter` into their respective scopes.

Comment: The point is to answer questions.  The answer to her question is "you have too many curly brackets."  Not, "here are some other completely un-related problems."

Comment: From the problem description: *"Write a program that will generate 1000 random integers in the range 0-49."* A complete answer needs to address that issue as well. You shouldn't be blaming us for pointing out the obvious. Rather consider not answering poor questions in the future. This is one of your responsibilities as well.

Comment: Number of good reasons for downvoting. Code only answer. Using `rand` and `srand` in 2016...

Comment: @user4581301 - Using C++ in 2016...?  You don't know the outside parameters regarding the OP's particular circumstance.  Maybe they have to use `rand` for some crazy reason?  I like to provide help and give answers.  I don't like punishing people for doing things the way I wouldn't do them.  The question was regarding the `for` loop.  I answered that question the best way I could, and it was accepted.  Anyone who doesn't like it can get bent.